# How can I start a process from powershell without bringing it to the front?

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a simple cleanup script for work which should include gpupdate. What I want to do is run gpupdate and capture the output or run it in another window and keep the current window on top. I've tried multiple different ways to run gpupdate.exe (including using WSH with the different focus options) but it always pops up in front of the current PowerShell window. PS commandlet Invoke-GPUpdate presents an error "Access is denied" so that doesn't seem to be a usable solution. I'm currently trying to call the ProcessGPUpdate API but I must have something wrong with my code. I don't really like this solution anyway as it doesn't look like it will give feedback/progress.

Reference API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wmi_v2/class-library/remotegpupdate-processgpupdate-method-string-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-uint32-string-microsoft-grouppolicy

My current non-working code

```
Add-Type '@
using Microsoft.GroupPolicy;
public static void ProcessGPUpdate(
string Computer,
bool force,
bool boot,
bool logoff,
bool sync,
uint delayInMinutes,
string target
)
'@
```

I'm open to suggestions on how to accomplish this. Currently, I'm considering running gpupdate minimized.

*Edit*:
Added command output as requested

```
PS H:\> $gpupdate = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { gpupdate.exe 2>$1 }
PS H:\> get-job

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData
Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------
--------             -------
1      Job1            BackgroundJob   Failed        False
localhost             gpupdate.exe 2>$1


PS H:\> Receive-Job -Name Job1
[localhost] The background process reported an error with the following
message: .
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [],
PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 2100,PSSessionStateBroken
PS H:\> $gpupdate = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { gpupdate.exe 2>$1 } -Name
gpupdate
PS H:\> Receive-Job -Name gpupdate
[localhost] The background process reported an error with the following
message: .
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [],
PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 2100,PSSessionStateBroken
PS H:\> $gpupdate = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { & "gpupdate.exe 2>$1" } -Name
gpupdate
PS H:\> Receive-Job -Name gpupdate
[localhost] The background process reported an error with the following
message: .
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [],
PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 2100,PSSessionStateBroken
[localhost] The background process reported an error with the following
message: .
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [],
PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 2100,PSSessionStateBroken
PS H:\> get-job

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData
Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------
--------             -------
1      Job1            BackgroundJob   Failed        False
localhost             gpupdate.exe 2>$1
3      gpupdate        BackgroundJob   Failed        False
localhost             gpupdate.exe 2>$1
5      gpupdate        BackgroundJob   Failed        False
localhost             & "gpupdate.exe 2>$1"
```

Comment: If you want to run a console application invisibly while still being able to capture its output, consider using [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) or, preferably, if available, [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob).

Comment: I haven't tried Start-ThreadJob but I've tried Start-Job multiple ways as well as Invoke-Command -AsJob and it always shows the status as failed with no other output/error

Comment: So it doesn't look like Start-ThreadJob is available on our computers >:-[

Comment: You seem to be trying various methods of achieving the same result without providing enough detail of each attempt/result for anyone to help you. `Invoke-GPUpdate` should work - assuming the user running the script has the correct permissions. Your Add-Type code wont work as your missing several important details (it has to be valid C# code). Example: https://dandraka.com/2018/11/12/powershell-how-do-you-add-inline-c/ - You need to define a namespace, class and method then instantiate an instance of `RemoteGPUpdate` and call `ProcessGPUpdate()` passing in the actual values you want to use

Comment: Being curious here, why do you not just run gpupdate directly?  Are you running it on remote computers using invoke-command?  Why are you using Start-Job and have you tried Start-Job with gpupdate?  Could you please provide the code for the things that you've tried and any error messages that you've received?

Comment: @MisterSmith I didn't want to clutter this up with all the things I've tried. I've been at this for a few days and really don't remember every different angle I've tested but I'll try some of the straightforward things again and post the output here

Comment: @Daniel The purpose of this script is for technicians to run locally when remoted into a client's computer. If I call gpupdate directly then it halts all other script execution until it finishes. If I start it as a separate instance then it pops up on top of the current powershell window

Comment: When I use Start-Job this is what happens

Comment: `Start-job -ScriptBlock { cmd /c gpupdate.exe } -Name gpupdate

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData
Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------
--------             -------
1      gpupdate        BackgroundJob   Running       False
localhost             cmd /c gpupdate.exe`

Comment: `PS H:\> get-job

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData
Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------
--------             -------
1      gpupdate        BackgroundJob   Failed        False
localhost             cmd /c gpupdate.exe`

Comment: I've tried various things like enclosing the command string in quotes, just calling gpudpate directly, specifying full path etc

Also, I couldn't tell you why Invoke-GPUpdate give access denied when we are directed to use gpudpate but that is controlled by GPO way above me so that's a roadblock as far as I'm concerned

Comment: Before trying to run this as a background job, I had tried to run gpupdate in it's own window and call User32 api to set powershell back to the foreground. This has it's own set of hurdles like having to wait for the conhost window to appear and detect that it is foreground before I can bring powershell back to the foreground

Comment: Another tangent was that I went looking for the Invoke-GPUpdate commandlet thinking I was going to pull the code to execute and hopefully remove whatever required elevation. But it looks like this is all in a GroupPolicy DLL so I won't be ripping anything from there

Comment: I did make some headway with some alternative Start-Job code I found here
https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/a-better-and-faster-start-job

Using this, I was able to start the background job and capture the output. Just seems heavy for what I need so I'm going to see if I can yank just what I need out of that

Comment: haha, please add any comments/code/etc you have directly to your post rather than in the comments, please :)  Use the edit button.

Comment: When you use Start-Job, do not use `cmd /c`, just `$job = Start-job -ScriptBlock {  gpupdate.exe 2>&1 } -Name gpupdate`  The 2>&1 is to redirect anything in the error stream to the success stream so you can recover it also from the job.  Once the job finishes (`$job.State -eq 'Completed'`) you can can get the output like `$job.ChildJobs.output` or `$job | Receive-Job`

Comment: @Daniel 
Looks the same as before and still no output. Added to OP as requested

Comment: Are you connected to another computer in a PSSession when you are getting those errors?  Seems to like there is something broken with powershell on the computer you are using.  Can you try the same thing from a different computer?

Comment: I have only tried this locally. I'm connected to an enterprise environment and I honestly don't know if I'm allowed to say any more than that. It's the end of my shift and I won't go back in until Tuesday but I can try to have some co-workers test it when I come back. In the meantime, I've got it working with that Start-JobInProcess from the link a couple comments above